# No result for padding-top with float: right

Tags: html, css

I have this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50"/>
    </div>
    <div class="add">
        <a href="#" class="link">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.menu .logo {
    float: left;
}
.menu .add {
    float: right;
}
.menu .add .link {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

but `padding-top` isn't working and I can't figure out why. I've tried with `margin-top: 20px;`, same result.

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jsv75/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link needs to be made block level with: `display: block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Jsv75/1/

```
.menu .add .link {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @KratalinJan sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes to look at a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the `.link` class in your css, like so:

```
.menu .add{
    color: white;
    background: red;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TJonS/hvaSs/

Answer (score 0):

You can't add padding top to an `a` tag as default, you need to make it an `inline-block` element

```
.menu .add .link {
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: red;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```